# How do i replace a particular image if i have position information of that image in gridview?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gridview

I am using gridview with image adapter to render images.

I want to know whether it is possible to replace a particular image if i have position information of that image?

For. e.g. i have a variable previous location in which i store the previous selected image position lets say its 1 (rectangle image). Now i want to replace the image at location 1 with some other image (square image). How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

check ,   getChildAt(position) API
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt(int)

once you get the reference to the particular childView , you can change the image.

Comment: thanks sat for replying. I have read the documentation i want to know whether is it correct:   View rv=grid_main.getChildAt(location); because there is no method setImageResource for rv

Comment: You have to get reference to the gridview ,                       GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridviewid) , then get the child using ImageView v = grid.getChild(position); v.setImageBitMap(bitmap);

Comment: I have to use ImageView v = (ImageView)grid.getChildAt(location);  v.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);  But when i run the application it shows application has stopped unexpectedly

Comment: Whats the errorLog ? If its ClassCast Exception , then check which view is being used in GridView child elements. try with View v and set background.

Comment: It shows following error:05-24 13:28:27.529: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(301): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-24 13:28:27.529: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(301): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
05-24 13:28:27.529: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(301):     at com.example.moodjournal.MoodJournal$ImageAdapter$1.onClick(MoodJournal.java:135)

Comment: I have two layout files main_switch.xml parent tag merge containing gridview and button( inside relative layout) and icon.xml file containing linear layout with imageview and textview